# .NET Generics(C#) in unmanaged environment(VB6.0)

Tags: c#, .net, generics, vb6, unmanaged

Given an API in a managed DLL(C#). Can an unmanaged environment such as VB6.0 able to use the following APIs?

Do VB6.0 supports this? :A

```
public static T CreateObject<T>() where T : new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

Do VB6.0 supports this? :B

```
public static T CreateObject()
{
    return new T();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as generics in VB 6. Also, COM doesn't support that, so you can't even use the managed DLL via COM in VB 6.

Comment: Even in (B) example, we can't convert it in COM? Thanks for guiding, I'm still rookie in unmanaged environment.

Comment: No, the B example can also not be used with COM. You'd have to replace `T` with `object`.

Comment: You should be able to do so, yes. It's just not type safe - you need to be sure that you're casting to the right type.

Comment: Ok I got it now: 'type-unsafe' is something to prevent. Actually I have one scenario of having a generic Parent-return-type, with different specific child-types instances to be return. That's why I was thinking to use generic :) Without generic, is there any good way? Or shall I just have multiple functions to return specific instance?